# Errors in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, null, typeerror

I just started with and code education, one of the first assignments is to build a webapplication.
For a good result the code has to run without error, unfortunately my code doens't run without error:

main.js:11 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null
    at main.js:11 nextBtn.addEventListener('click',nextSlide);

When I comment this out the next error returns:
main.js:12 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null
    at main.js:12

When I comment this out the next error returns:
main.js:27 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getcontext' of null
    at main.js:27

These errors occured when I got the standard template from bootstrap.

Any help would be appriciated.

I would also like to use jquery for form validation, but $ isn't recognised by Visuals studio code

Regards,

Bas

```
enter code here     https://jsfiddle.net/Basso/vkrogpf6/3/

<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="CSS/style.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <title>Eindopdracht WebOntwikkeling</title>
  </head>
  <body>

      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">

          <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>

          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
              <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="index.html">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="Form.html">Formulier</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="audio_video.html">Audio Video</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="Afbeeldingen.html">Afbeeldingen</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item">
                      <a class="nav-link" href="Blog.html">Blog</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="Krant.html">Nieuws</a>
                      </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </nav>
 <canvas class="myCanvas1"></canvas> 

<img id="myImage" src="../Eindopdracht/Images/bcg-3.jpg" alt="palmboom" />

<svg id="mySvg" height="210" width="400">
  <path d="M150 0 L75 200 L225 200 Z" />
</svg>


    <script src="JS/main.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>

    const nextBtn = document.querySelector('.nextBtn');
const prevBtn = document.querySelector('.prevBtn');


nextBtn.addEventListener('click',nextSlide);
prevBtn.addEventListener('click',prevSlide);


function nextSlide(){

    document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url('Images/bcg-3.jpg')";

}

function prevSlide(){
    document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url('Images/bcg-4.jpg')";
}


var canvas = document.querySelector("myCanvas1");
var ctx = canvas.getcontext("2d");
var img = document.getElementById ("myImage");
ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0,canvas.width, canvas.height);



enter code here 

<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
     <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="CSS/style.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <title>Eindopdracht WebOntwikkeling</title>
  </head>
  <body class="page1">

      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">

          <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>

          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
              <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="index.html">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="Form.html">Formulier</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="audio_video.html">Audio Video</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="Afbeeldingen.html">Afbeeldingen</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item">
                      <a class="nav-link" href="Blog.html">Blog</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="Krant.html">Nieuws</a>
                      </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </nav>




  <button type="button" class="btn prevBtn">PrevBtn</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn nextBtn">NextBtn</button>


    <script src="JS/main.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery-validation@1.19.1/dist/jquery.validate.js"></script> 
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: where is nextBtn class is present in html?

Comment: Sorry the the page consist of multiple .html files. The buttons are in the index.html

Answer (score 0):

You do not have a button with `nextBtn` class... you'll get the same errors on `prevBtn`.

And since you're trying to add an event listener to non-existant html elements you get these errors.

Add the buttons to your html, or change current button class to `nextBtn` and you'll be good to go.